# Hash.each doesn't return a hash?

Tags: ruby

`Hash.each` returns an array `[key, value]`,
but if I want a hash?

Example: `{:key => value }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant "yields" where you said "return" because `Hash#each` already returns a hash (the receiver).

To answer your question: If you need a hash with the key and the value you can just create one. Like this:

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  kv_hash = {key => value}
  do_something_with(kv_hash)
end
```

There is no alternative `each` method that yields hashs, so the above is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to transform the hash somehow, so I will give you my solution to this problem, which may be not exactly the same. To modify a hash, you have to `.map` them and construct a new hash.

This is how I reverse key and values:

```
h = {:a => 'a', :b => 'b'}
Hash[h.map{ |k,v| [v, k] }]
# => {"a"=>:a, "b"=>:b}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `.each` with two parameters:

```
>> a = {1 => 2, 3 => 4}
>> a.each { |b, c|
?>     puts "#{b} => #{c}"
>>   }
1 => 2
3 => 4
=> {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` the hash to a list of single-element hashes, then call `each` on the list:

```
h = {:a => 'a', :b => 'b'}
h.map{ |k,v| {k => v}}.each{ |x| puts x }
```